# Swift: SortDescriptor not working with a KeyPath to an enum represented by an Int

Tags: swift

In my model, I have a property `category` of type `Category` (en Enum represented by an Int16). I want to use the new [SortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/sortdescriptor/3802537-init) with the `category` property but the compiler complains that `No exact matches in call to initializer`. It's working fine with the rawCategory, or if I use a NSSortDescriptor.

Is there a way to make it work with the enum instead?

```
class Book: NSObject {
    var category: Category
    var rawCategory: Int16

    init(category: Category) {
        self.category = category
        self.rawCategory = category.rawValue
    }
}

enum Category: Int16 {
    case actionAdventure
    case classics
    case comic
    case detective
    case fantasy
}

func makeSortDescriptor() {
    let categorySortDescriptor = SortDescriptor(\Book.category) // No exact matches in call to initializer
    let rawCategorySortDescriptor = SortDescriptor(\Book.rawCategory)

    let categoryNSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Book.category, ascending: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an overload to match [every single one of the existing initializers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/sortdescriptor) that you want to forward to.

```swift
extension SortDescriptor where Compared: NSObject {
  init<RawRepresentable: Swift.RawRepresentable>(
    _ keyPath: KeyPath<Compared, RawRepresentable>,
    order: SortOrder = .forward
  ) where RawRepresentable.RawValue == Int16 {
    self.init(keyPath.appending(path: \.rawValue), order: order)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jessy. I realised I can also use `let categorySortDescriptor = SortDescriptor(\Book.category.rawValue)`. But creating an overload will be useful if I use this in many places.